# TYPO3 Extension jpfaq does not work (problem with the database?)

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I recently tried to create an FAQ Page with the TYPO3 extension jpfaq.

I did set up everything as it was described in the manual. But for some reason when i preview the page, it shows a bunch of different error. For example:

```
TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\Generic\Storage\Exception\SqlErrorException
Table 'xxx_typo_dev.tx_jpfaq_domain_model_ttcontent' doesn't exist
```

When I "unbind" the FAQ database I created it shows me the correct FAQ page (just without the questions and answers). So there might be a problem with the database?

Cleared cache. Deleted and installed the extension again. Didn't help.

Comment: what TYPO3 version do you use? how did you install the extension?

Comment: 9.5.20 i install it by uploading the zip file

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the you need to fix the `Database Structure`.
Normally the `Database Structure` is fixed when you install new extensions in the `Extensions` module.

If you use `Composer Mode` the installation is done with composer and you need to fix it by hand.
This can be done in the InstallTool / Maintenance Module: `Analyze Database Structure`.
Or you use the commandline: `vendor/helhum/typo3-console/typo3cms database:updateschema` (don't forget to use `composer require helhum/typo3-console`)

Comment: But i did use the extensions module

Comment: anyway you should try to fix it by "Analyze Database Structure". At least there you should be shown what changes TYPO3 will do to your database - and whether the DB-update will fail. If no changes (creating table) are necessary your zip-file might be corrupt or at least the file `ext_tables.sql` has errors.